# Expand a NominalDiffTime by a factor

Tags: haskell

Using the `time` library in Haskell, I have computed `delta :: NominalDiffTime` previously in my program, and I have a `successFactor :: Double`, `successFactor = 2.8`. I would want to (naively) compute
a new `deltaExpanded :: NominalDiffTime`:

```
deltaExpanded = delta * successFactor
```

However, I get the error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘time1.9.3:Data.Time.Clock.Internal.NominalDiffTime.NominalDiffTime’ with actual type ‘Double’
```

Not being very good at Haskell coding yet, I would like to know what the simplest perform the computation would be.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing is to just change the type signature for your factor.

```
successFactor :: NominalDiffTime
```

If you must have `successFactor :: Double` for some reason, you can convert just before multiplying:

```
realToFrac :: Double -> NominalDiffTime
```

Comment: `successFactor :: NominalDiffTime` doesn't make a lot of sense to me. A NominalDiffTime represents milliseconds, while 2.8 in the question is supposed to be a scalar multiplier. And I would be pretty nervous about using `realToFrac` before multiplying, since "Conversion functions such as...realToFrac will treat it as seconds. For example, (0.010 :: NominalDiffTime) corresponds to 10 milliseconds." What internal representation will 2.8 be converted to, and what will the multiplication mean?

Comment: @amalloy Yes, the units on multiplication don't make much sense. You should think of `x*y` as actually being shorthand for `x*y/(1 second)`. This is what makes `successFactor :: NominalDiffTime; successFactor = 2.8` the correct solution -- the "conversion function" of `fromInteger` makes `2.8` mean `2.8 seconds`, and so `x*2.8 seconds/1 second` is `x*2.8` with an actually unitless `2.8`.

Comment: @amalloy There are two essentially arbitrary decisions made in my last comment: one is that `fromInteger` means `(*1 second)`, and the other is that `(*)` means `(*)/1 second`, and the `1 second` in each could reasonably be any other period of time. The two choices were made to cancel each other specifically so that multiplying by a literal does the Right Thing.